# Mongo sort by single enum and other field

Tags: mongodb

On my collection I have the fields:

```
{
  ...
  status: ['scheduled', 'sent', 'error']
  sendDate: Date()
}
```

My objective is to show the `scheduled` first, and then the `error` and `sent` sorted by `{ sendDate: -1 }`. I would do 2 queries, but I want to keep it paginated. Because of different timezones, the `sendDate` might end up as `scheduled` before other that are already `sent`. Like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  sendDate: ISODate("2019-06-11T19:28:50.617Z"),
  status: 'scheduled'
}, {
  id: 2,
  sendDate: ISODate("2019-06-12T19:28:50.617Z"),
  status: 'sent'
}, {
  id: 3,
  sendDate: ISODate("2019-06-10T19:28:50.617Z"),
  status: 'scheduled'
}, {
  id: 4,
  sendDate: ISODate("2019-06-10T19:28:50.617Z"),
  status: 'sent'
}, {
  id: 5,
  sendDate: ISODate("2019-06-11T19:28:50.617Z"),
  status: 'error'
}
```

The expected sorted id's would be:

```
{
  id: 1,
  status: 'scheduled'
},{ 
  id: 3,
  status: 'scheduled'
},{ 
  id: 2,
  status: 'sent'
},{ 
  id: 5,
  status: 'error'
},{ 
  id: 4,
  status: 'sent'
}
```

Comment: You mean if there 5 scheduled, 5 sent and 3 errors. Then, the first 5 should be scheduled (sorted by date), next 5 should be sent (sorted by date) and so on. Right?

Comment: No. The first 5 must be scheduled (sorted by date). Everything else, sorted by date.

Comment: it would be better if you can you share input dataset (at least 3-4 records) and expected output (current one is very much ambiguous)

Comment: @RajatGoel edited the question a little better

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this at run time by adding a field (priority), and sorting based on both priority and DateTime ;

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {"$addFields" : {
        "priority" :  {"$cond": { if: { $eq: [ "$status", "scheduled" ] }, then: 2, else: 1 }}
        }
    },
    {"$sort" : {"priority" : -1, "sendDate" : -1}}
])
```

Though not a very good solution for very large (records in millions) collections
Running eg. https://mongoplayground.net/p/0oEZyOyUCCH

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of sorting like this.

Add a `priority` field to each document which gives you the ability to sorting.

scheduled has more `priority` than others. Then sort on this field.

For example, give priority `0` `scheduled`, and `1` to anything else at this state. By sorting `Ascending` on the `priority` field, you can achieve what you want. Of course, by adding different priority to each type of documents, you can handle the ordering process. (e.g. scheduled:0, sent:1, error:2)

Using this approach, You can add `priority` to any kind of documents that should process sooner than others. It does not depend on document status, so if you add any other statuses in the future, it can be handled easily.

So your documents should be like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  sendDate: ISODate("2019-06-11T19:28:50.617Z"),
  status: 'scheduled',
  priority: 0
}, {
  id: 2,
  sendDate: ISODate("2019-06-12T19:28:50.617Z"),
  status: 'sent',
  priority: 1
}, {
  id: 3,
  sendDate: ISODate("2019-06-10T19:28:50.617Z"),
  status: 'scheduled',
  priority: 1
}, {
  id: 4,
  sendDate: ISODate("2019-06-10T19:28:50.617Z"),
  status: 'sent',
  priority: 1
}, {
  id: 5,
  sendDate: ISODate("2019-06-11T19:28:50.617Z"),
  status: 'error',
  priority: 1
}
```

and your order:

```
{
  "priority": 1,
  "sendDate": -1
}
```